# Why can't I get the function to print vector[count]?

Tags: c++, arrays

```
//  
//  main.cpp
//  Array
//
//  Created by Rusty on 9/21/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Rusty. All rights reserved.
//
```

Larger Than n
In a program, write a function that accepts three arguments: an array, the
size of the array, and a number n . Assume that the array contains integers. The 
function should display all of the numbers in the array that are greater than the number n .

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

// prototype
void arrayFunct(int[], int, int);

int main()
{

    const int SIZE_OF_ARRAY = 8;
    int array[SIZE_OF_ARRAY] = {1,2,3,4,5};   // Unused variable 'array'
    int number_n = 2;                         // Unused variable 'number_n'

    cout << "x" << endl;    // test print 'x'
    int x = 7;
    cout << x << endl;      // test print variable

    void arrayFunct (int array[], int SIZE_OF_ARRAY, int number_n);

    return 0;

}

void arrayFunct(int vector[], int sz, int n)
   {
       cout << sz;
       for(int count = 0; count < sz; count++)
           {
               if (vector[count] > n) // ex: if vector[0] > 2, print 
               {
                   cout << vector[count] << endl;
               }
           }
   }
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: `void arrayFunct (int array[], int SIZE_OF_ARRAY, int number_n);` are you expecting this to invoke the `arrayFunct()` function?

Comment: Build Succeeded, but nothing in the arrayFunct is printed. Only printed on screen is: 
x
7

Comment: @Frank, I'm trying to send the three parameters, is that what they're called?, to the void arrayFunct function to find out the numbers larger than n to be printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's have something wrong while u call a function

change this in main

```
void arrayFunct (int array[], int SIZE_OF_ARRAY, int number_n);
```

into

```
arrayFunct(array, SIZE_OF_ARRAY, number_n);
```

They don't need to assign type for it.

Comment: That's what I thought too, but when I tried it earlier I got the "Variable has incomplete type 'void'" error.

Comment: And then I removed void.  Is what is printed in the successful build.  83
4
5

Comment: I use edit this code on tuitorialsport onlince c++ compiler.
http://tpcg.io/hPFkWb

Comment: cuz u "cout << sz;" it's = 8 and not use endl
that's mean 8 3 4 5  not 83

Comment: just remove this line "cout << sz;" it's will be ur answer